# Is there a way, in pexpect to get the content of parenthesized sub-expressions

Tags: python-3.x, regex, parsing, pexpect

I'm analyzing data coming from a program with pexpect. Is there a way to get an array with the parts matching parenthesized sub-expressions ? E.g.:

```
p.expect("IP: *([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*) *\r\n")
```

I'd like to get a list or a tuple with the four fields of my IP.

Comment: Side note: you probably want to use `[0-9]+` (or `[0-9]{1,3}`) instead of `[0-9]*`; otherwise, you could end up matching three dots.

Answer (score 1):

Pexpect sets a match attribute on the spawn, which is a plain old [`re.Match` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). So, look in the [groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups) i.e. `p.match.groups()` for the matched octets after a successful `p.expect` call.